# ListView with an element opening a Dialog

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, react-navigation

I will do my best to explain my situation.

I gather an array of "events", then the `ListView` process all this rows, to show as I expected.

```
<ListView
   dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
   enableEmptySections={true} // For warning...
   renderRow={(rowData) => <EventComponent data={rowData} />}
/>
```

`<EventComponent />` is the one that renders all the rows.

The requirement that I need to do now it's:
*Show more information about every event, clicking on the event's title* (in other words, click and popup)

The first that it came to my mind it was **Modal**

```
class EventComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        modalVisible: false,
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.userDefined.event}>

            <MoreInfo data={this.props.data} show={this.state.modalVisible}/>   <------ my solution

            <View style={{flex:0.02, backgroundColor: this.props.data.color}} />
            <View style={{flex: 0.98, marginLeft: 5}}>
                <Text onLongPress={() => !this.state.modalVisible} style={[styles.userDefined.eventName, {color: this.props.data.color}]}>{this.props.data.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.userDefined.eventBy}>{this.props.data.owner}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.userDefined.eventContent}>{this.props.data.startTime} - {this.props.data.endTime}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.userDefined.eventContent}>Espacio: {this.props.data.space}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
}
```

The `<MoreInfo />` component was my solution so far, but I have two problems (and this is how It proves that i'm a newbie with react)

1. I need to show the Modal (`<MoreInfo />`) when I press on the event (`<EventComponent />`)
2. I need to retrieve an `event_id` (already assigned in `<EventComponent />` with `this.props.data.event_id`) into the Modal `<MoreInfo />` and with that, do a query to the db and show a result.

What do you think? Can it be possible?

Best regards my friends

Comment: This is more of a design issue, but what you want to do is keep the sources intact and not in a component. This way, by mapping each source, you have the value to manipulate. 
Ex. this.state.sources.map(obj => <a onClick={...}>{obj.title}</a>);

Comment: Sorry, but it seems a bit confusing to me your answer.

What i need is to pass to the component `<MoreInfo />` the id from its parent component, `<EventComponent />`, but I can't retrieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you did is exactly right . 
I mean it is reasonable to use a state `modalvisible` to control the visibility of your modal ( dialog actually) and pass `this.props.data` to your modal.

So what do you worry about?  There is no need to consider the best practice If there is no problems during your usage .  :)

Comment: Let's stick with that for now! Time is short to end this project. Thank you! :D